# How to substitute/mask values inside html tags in unix using AWK?

Tags: html, bash, shell, mask, data-masking

I have a html file with sensitive data. I want to mask those values , how can i do that using AWK ? I am fairly new to shell scripting so if you can help me with the code, that will be highly appreciated.

**input file**

```
<html>
<body>
<hr><br><>span class="table">Records</span><table>
<tr class="column">
 <td>ID</td>
 <td>Name</td>
 <td>Address</td>
 <td>City</td>
 <td>Code</td>
 <td>Account</td>
 <td>Phone</td>
 <td>Country</td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
<td>12345678</td>
<td>James Watson</td>
<td>Ivy Estate Rd</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>NY03XXXX</td>
<td>00003458</td>
<td></td>
<td>United States</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**expected output**

```
<html>
<body>
<hr><br><>span class="table">Records</span><table>
<tr class="column">
 <td>ID</td>
 <td>Name</td>
 <td>Address</td>
 <td>City</td>
 <td>Code</td>
 <td>Account</td>
 <td>Phone</td>
 <td>Country</td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
<td>1##4##7#</td>
<td>J##e# #a##o#</td>
<td>I## E##a## R#</td>
<td>N## Y##k</td>
<td>N##3##X#</td>
<td>0##0##5#</td>
<td></td>
<td>United States</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It depends on the assumption you have on your input file. Can it be any wellformed HTML text, or does it always have the structure you posted, i.e. each `<td>....</td>` in its own line?

Comment: thats right, it always has the same structure as such <td>....</td> in its own line.

Comment: In this case, I would read the file line by line,  until you arrive at a `<tr class="data">` line. After this, I would pick all `<td>....</td>` lines and transform what's between the tags in the way you like.

Comment: not every <td> tag will hold a value though, also not every value inside <td> tag needs to be masked.

Comment: The former is not a problem (an empty tag simply stays empty), but how do you know which one needs to be masked?

Comment: yes , so theres a list of tags that needs masking , from which i identified the tags. and these tags will be consistent through out the file.

Comment: Then you parse also the lines from the `<tr class="column">`  part and remember the index position of the item(s) which you don't want to mask.

Comment: This sounds a lil complicated to me. Perhaps you can post a code snippet for the same?

Comment: I don't understand: Do you have problems designing the _algorithm_, or do you have problem _implementing_ it? In the first case, please state so in your question, and tag it with _algorithm_. In the second case, please show the part you have implemented already, and indicate at which point you are stuck. I don't think that people here will work a complete program for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know,  AWK is not well-suited for hierarchical structured text like HTML. If you still insist, maybe you can try to use global variable to indicate which lines should be handled. And finally, your code may seems like below

```
BEGIN {
    flag=0
}

{
    if(flag) {
        if(match($0, "</tr>")) {
            flag = 0
            print
        } else {
            # run your replacement code here
            print
        }
    } else {
        print
        if(match($0, "class=\"data\"")) {
            flag = 1
        }
    }
}
```